# Android: How to show a fragment over parent activity and its button/nav views

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-view, bottomnavigationview

I have a main activity that launches a fragment through a fragment transaction. I want the fragment to **completely** fill the screen, showing no views at all from the parent. However, when I commit the fragment transaction I can still see the bottom nav view of the parent activity as well as it's buttons. I made a little demo app to show what I mean:

The main activity has a yellow background. The "Testclick" button starts a fragment transaction using the code below.

[image]

This is the result of the transaction. The red background of the fragment is now visible, but the bottomNavigationView and Buttons remain visible (Which is not desired).

[image]

Fragment Transaction

```
bttn.setOnClickListener {
            supportFragmentManager
                .beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.contentview, Frag1())
                .addToBackStack(null)
                .commit()
        }
```

Main Activity layout

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/contentview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/yellow"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

...

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your R.id.contentview must be in the background behind the buttons

Ah actually you know what there is a good tool, called LayoutInspector in Tools -> Layout inspector, you can actually see how the layout is set up while your activity is running. In your case the layout of fragment is added inside the layout of activity.

Sorry didnt see the id at first

Comment: Hmm I see. How do I prevent the layout of my fragment from being added inside the activity layout? I am doing the fragment transaction on the root ConstraintView of my main activity. Is that view not high enough in the view hierarchy? I've attached a photo of what my LayoutInspector looks like in the post for you to see

Comment: Yeah you see id.content is the main layout. So if you were to replace 
                .replace(R.id.contentview, Frag1());   with 
                .replace(android.R.id.content, Frag1());  I think that would work for what you need. Every activity root id is android.R.id.content. Although as you can see depending on the theme there might me some other stuff such action_bar

Comment: Oh amazing, I didn't know you could get system IDs like that. However that only partially worked. The red fragment covers the whole activity but the buttons from the activity are still clickable even though they are covered. I've attached a photo of this as a reference. In it I am clicking the "Toast" button from the main activity even though the fragment is covering it. Any idea how to prevent that?

Comment: Yeah you have to set the root layout of your fragment clickable android:clickable="true". That way it consumes the click event and doesn't let it propagate through the layout.

Comment: That worked! Thanks a bunch for your patience and helping me figure this out!